# How can I increase cell refrence incrementally in a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have created a workbook that keeps track of training totals by week. I am using this current formula:

```
=SUM(Schedule!G3:G9)
```

Which works, but for the next week, I am manually having to change `G3:G9` to `G10:G16`. I am looking for a way that I can create the formula so I can drag the formula and have it automatailly increase the referenced range by 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX and some math:

```
=SUM(INDEX(Schedule!G:G,(ROW(A1)-1)*7+3):INDEX(Schedule!G:G,(ROW(A1)-1)*7+9))
```